# ZipDotNet return file paths from directory to zip

Tags: c#, wpf

I have managed to get the files from an archive but i am getting values like this...

```
ZipEntry://path/to/file
```

How would i just get the files path like so...

```
path/to/file
```

Here is my code thus far

```
internal static Array GetFiles(string haystack, string needle = "*")
{
  var resources = ZipFile.Read(ResourcePath);
  resources.Password = ResourcePassword;
  return resources.SelectEntries(needle, haystack).ToArray();
}
```

Please note this is bare bones code with no error checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the ZipEntry prefix for each of the entries.

```
path.Replace("ZipEntry://", "");
```

Comment: That simple, i feel somewhat belittled now.